# How to create list of string with special format in excel by VBA

Tags: excel, vba, list

I have column in excel with values like this:

```
Column_Name
row1
row2
row3
```

and I need create a string variable from that by VBA in this format

```
('row1','row2','row3')
```

I have this code

```
   Dim Strg As String
   With Range(Range("E2"), Range("E2").End(xlDown))
      Strg = Replace(Application.Trim(Join(Application.Transpose(.Value), " ")), " ", ",")
   End With
```

But it gives me only `row1,row2,row3` I don't know How to put it in between ' ' and add parentheses to the beginning and end.
Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you are trying?

```
Dim Strg As String
With Range(Range("E2"), Range("E2").End(xlDown))
    Strg = Replace(Application.Trim(Join(Application.Transpose(.Value), " ")), " ", "','")
End With

Debug.Print "('" & Strg & "')"
```

Comment: No, this give me ('row1,row2,row3') and i need ('row1','row2','row3'). The ' must be between each row, not just begginig and end

Comment: Are you sure you copied the code as I pasted it? I think you missed the the `"','"` part :D